# Calculate from two joined aggregate queries

Tags: mysql

I have two aggregate subqueries that I want to calculate. The query works fine with out the final calculation, but when I add in the sum calculation from both subqueries it groups it all into one sum.

The setup is two tables one (parentpayments) has payments that I want to group to get total payments. The other (servicelog) has times sent and the rate for the time. The service is issued to the child so I need to look up the parent ID from the child. I need the total balance, so I'm finding the difference between the Due calculated and the Paid.

Query I am using is:

```
SELECT PID, b.Due, a.Paid, SUM(b.Due - a.Paid) FROM 
(SELECT Person AS par, SUM(Amount) AS Paid FROM parentpayments GROUP BY pp.Person) AS a 
JOIN 
(SELECT p.ID AS PID, SUM(l.Time * l.Rate) AS Due FROM servicelog AS l INNER JOIN children AS c ON c.ID = l.Child INNER JOIN people AS p ON p.ID = c.Parent GROUP BY p.ID) AS b 
ON PID = Par
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause in the outer query too.

Comment: That's it. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. You actually should remove `SUM()` and just use `b.Due - a.Paid` instead.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel They both worked, any specific reason for just using sum, or just for query optimization?

Comment: Aggregation is just unnecessary in the outer query. In best case there is no difference. In worst case you waste ressources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `SUM()` in the outer query. `PID` and `Par` are already unique in the subqueries. So it doesn't make sense to group by one of them. But if you use SUM() without GROUP BY you will get only one row and selecting `PID`, `Due` and `Paid` wouldn't make sense. So all you need is just to remove `SUM()`:

```
SELECT PID, b.Due, a.Paid, b.Due - a.Paid FROM 
(SELECT Person AS par, SUM(Amount) AS Paid FROM parentpayments GROUP BY pp.Person) AS a 
JOIN 
(SELECT p.ID AS PID, SUM(l.Time * l.Rate) AS Due FROM servicelog AS l INNER JOIN children AS c ON c.ID = l.Child INNER JOIN people AS p ON p.ID = c.Parent GROUP BY p.ID) AS b 
ON PID = Par
```

You could though use your query and append `GROUP BY PID`. But that is as well as to group by a primary key. Every group would contain exactly one row. And SUM() wouzld be equal to its parameter.

There is also another Method to achieve the same result. You can use UNION instead of a JOIN - and the you will need `SUM()`. Note that in this case you cannot select `Due` and `Paid` separately - only the balance:

```
SELECT PID, SUM(amount) as balance
FROM (
    SELECT Person AS PID, SUM(Amount) AS amount
    FROM parentpayments
    GROUP BY pp.Person
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.ID AS PID, -SUM(l.Time * l.Rate) AS amount
    FROM servicelog AS l
    INNER JOIN children AS c ON c.ID = l.Child
    INNER JOIN people AS p ON p.ID = c.Parent
    GROUP BY p.ID
) AS x
GROUP BY PID
```

Comment: seems like we might want a query to anticipate an amounts due which don't have any related `parentpayment`. i'd get the amount due and then an outer join to the payments, so we dont skip over amounts due where no payment is made.

Comment: @spencer7593 I didn't really try to look behind the business logic. For me it's still not clear, which value cannot exist without the other. If in doubt, I'd rather use UNION instead of a JOIN (while `paid` is negated in the subquery) and the use `SUM()`.

Comment: i can't but help look at what a query is attempting to do, what result we are actually trying to achieve, ... and i cant help but subconsciously plan the test cases that are going to run.  i can't (in good conscience) post an answwer with a  "solution" that I know (or anticipate) is wrong in a significant way, without adding a note about it in my answer.

Comment: @spencer7593 Yes, you are correct. I do need the due and unpaid values as the report is for outstanding accounts. I originally had a left join from due to the paid. When I was trying to figure out how to ungroup the results I switched it around.